# Aliasing in the names of function arguments (double naming)

Tags: python, constraints, batch-processing, maya

Are the functions able to have double names for their arguments in Python?
I mean a short and full form of the variable name.

I'll try to be more clear. Everybody who is familiar with Autodesk Maya knows
a function to make constraints. It has some flags and you can use the short or the long form of it's name:

> maintainOffset(mo), weight(w), layer(l) and so on..

So you can call this function with different names of it's arguments but it gives you the same result:

```
cmds.parentConstraint(driverObj, drivenObj, maintainOffset=True, weight=1.0,..)
cmds.parentConstraint(driverObj, drivenObj, maintainOffset=True, w=1.0,..)
cmds.parentConstraint(driverObj, drivenObj, mo=True, weight=1.0,..)
cmds.parentConstraint(driverObj, drivenObj, mo=True, w=True,..)
```

**How to implement this type of behaviour in Python** 2.7.x? I'm using the documentation actively but still can't find the answer.

*Besides I have defined 4 functions for various types of the contraints:*

```
# Parent Constraint
def doParentConstraint(lst, mo = True, w = 1.0, sr = 'None', st = 'None', l = 'None'):
    for pair in lst:
        cmds.parentConstraint(pair[0], pair[1], maintainOffset = mo, weight = w,
                                skipRotate = sr, skipTranslate = st, layer = l)
# Orient Constraint
def doOrientConstraint(lst, mo = False, w = 1.0, o = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), sk = 'None', l = 'None'):
    for pair in lst:
        cmds.orientConstraint(pair[0], pair[1], maintainOffset = mo, weight = w, 
                                offset = o, skip = sk, layer = l)
# Point Constraint
def doPointConstraint(lst, mo = False, w = 1.0, o = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), sk = 'None', l = 'None'):
    for pair in lst:
        cmds.orientConstraint(pair[0], pair[1], maintainOffset = mo, weight = w, 
                                offset = o, skip = sk, layer = l)
# Scale Constraint
def doScaleConstraint(lst, mo = False, w = 1.0, o = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), sk = 'None', l = 'None'):
    for pair in lst:
        cmds.orientConstraint(pair[0], pair[1], maintainOffset = mo, weight = w, 
                                offset = o, skip = sk, layer = l)
```

*Connection List:*

```
cLst = produceConnectionList(tNodesA, tNodesB)
```

*And some sort of **wrapper** function for all of these:*

```
def batchConnect(type = "parentConstraint", ???):
    cLst = produceConnectionList(tNodesA, tNodesB)
    if type is "parentConstraint": doParentConstraint(cLst, ???)
    if type is "orientConstraint": doOrientConstraint(cLst, ???)
    if type is "pointConstraint": doPointConstraint(cLst, ???)
    if type is "scaleConstraint": doScaleConstraint(cLst, ???)
```

But I don't know how to pass values between these functions and the wrapper because although they have the same number of arguments but the names of arguments and those types a little bit differ.

Also I want to have an opportunity to use short and the full form of the flag names when I'm calling the wrapper:

```
batchConnect("pointConstraint", mo=False, offset=(0,0,0), weight=1)
batchConnect("pointConstraint", maintainOffset=False, o=(0,0,0), w=1)
```

Must do the same.

```
batchConnect("pointConstraint")
```

Without arguments must call *doPointConstraint()* with default values.

```
batchConnect()
```

Without specifying the type and arguments at all must call by default *doParentConstraint()* with these default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to do this in some of my scripts:

```
def myExample(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("width") and kwargs.get("w"):
        cmds.error("same flag used two times")
    else:
        myWidth = kwargs.get("width") or kwargs.get("w") or "nothing"
    print(myWidth)
    
myExample(width=200)
```

If you have to this multiple times, it may be easy to create a custom class:

```
class mimicKwargs:
    def __init__(self, labelLong, labelShort, defautValue,kwargDic):
        if kwargDic.get(labelLong) and kwargDic.get(labelShort):
            cmds.error("same flag used two times")
        else:
            self.userInput = kwargDic.get(labelLong) or kwargDic.get(labelShort) or defautValue
    def output(self):
        return self.userInput
          
def myExample(**kwargs):
    
    myWidth = mimicKwargs("width", "w", 150, kwargs).output()
    
    print(myWidth)

myExample(width=200)#
myExample()#print 150
```

Answer (score 8):

If I've correctly understood what you're after, the easiest way to do this is with `**kwargs` "magic" and [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), for example:

```
def demo(maintain_offset=None, **config):
    if maintain_offset is None:  # if not supplied by 'real name'
        maintain_offset = config.get('mo', 'baz')  # check alias, fall back to default
    print maintain_offset
```

*(note compliance with the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))*. In use:

```
>>> demo(maintain_offset="foo")
foo
>>> demo(mo="bar")
bar
>>> demo()
baz
```

If this syntax is unfamiliar, see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761)

---

For a more generic approach, you can use the decorator syntax to wrap a function with a set of aliases:

```
import functools

def alias(aliases):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(**kwargs):
            for name, alias in aliases.items():
                if name not in kwargs and alias in kwargs:
                    kwargs[name] = kwargs[alias]
            return func(**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

In use:

```
>>> @alias({'maintain_offset': 'mo'})
def demo(maintain_offset='baz', **kwargs):
    print maintain_offset


>>> demo(maintain_offset="foo")
foo
>>> demo(mo="bar")
bar
>>> demo()
baz
```

Comment: I don't really ever do decorators, but should `wrapper` be `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` and the return statement be `return func(*args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes, that would be necessary to also support any positional arguments, but I thought that would only muddy the waters at this point.

Comment: Jonrsharpe I need the time to think about your words and try to implement your idea !

Comment: This will result in an unexpected keyword argument error if the alias is not removed from kwargs before calling func.

Comment: That's true @MuslimbekAbduganiev; if the target `func` doesn't accept arbitrary `**kwargs` you'll also need to `del kwargs[alias]`.