# Keyword arguments aliases in python

Tags: python, parameters, keyword-argument

It always seemed odd to me that there are keyword arguments (or arguments) that can be passed to functions or `__init__` methods of classes. How do you prevent user who is not familiar to your code from making a mistake? How to get user instantly ( almost instinctively ) familiar to your code without badly written or long winded documentation or to many trials and errors preventing user from quickly and comfortably use your code or module ?

In python we are lucky since we have `help` and `dir` functions that can often guide us to better understanding what some function parameters are. But sometimes there is poorly written `__doc__` string that explains nothing.

Let me give you some examples of what i mean:

```
    >>> help(str.lower)
    Help on method_descriptor:

        lower(...)
        S.lower() -> string

    Return a copy of the string S converted to lowercase
```

.
For example here we have some function that have **...** input parameters. What does this parameter stands for, for complete newbie ( as was I when i first dived into python ) this was confusing and often i just skipped this section.

Some of websites that offer advice or tutorial just print-out help function file or just implement 1 of many functionalities of sed function.

[1 functionality of example function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm)

or directly from python.org

*str.lower()

Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters [4] converted to lowercase.
For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.*

Now for someone who just started programing and don't ( or can't ) dive into bits and bytes , addresses and etc, this is some ancient spell that only master warlock can perform, don't even let me started on why this is not helping for non-english speaking people.

For this particular example function i can figure out 2-3 additional examples where it can do its job in different way, also i had to find out that this example function could be used by imputing string into `str.lower(here)` part.

The big problem here ( as i see it of course ) is that str with little googling can be descriptive by itself, and its functionality can be logically concluded only via wikipedia.

If i summarize the questions is simple, is there a way to modify the keywords when using as parameters to accept more names than we define so user would not have to rip his/her hair of on first step of the introduction tutorial?

Now i know some of you guys will say something along the lines : "if you dont understand it, don't do it" or "i ain't yo mama to teach you stuff"... to that i have to say "sharing is caring" and "You sometimes need help coding too otherwise you would not be on this website ".

Answer (score 4):

I made this decorator to alias kwargs. Works like a charm

```py
def alias_param(param_name: str, param_alias: str) -> Callable:
    """
    Decorator for aliasing a param in a function

    Args:
        param_name: name of param in function to alias
        param_alias: alias that can be used for this param
    Returns:
    """
    def decorator(func: Callable):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            alias_param_value = kwargs.get(param_alias)
            if alias_param_value:
                kwargs[param_name] = alias_param_value
                del kwargs[param_alias]
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
```

it then can be used like so

```py
@alias_param("param_1", alias='p1')
def function(param_1=None):
    return param_1

function(p1='value')
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374525/699665

Comment: You forget to return decoorator.

Answer (score 0):

This is mine solution if someone has better please comment or correct.

**the idea:**
The idea is that every class could have a list of aliases to specific attributes so user could (based on class name logic :> point needs x,y,z,name attributes, dog needs breed,name,age,sex attributes and so on ) based on its own internal logic to call attributes without need for knowing exactly what attribute name sed attribute have.

**the logic:**
If *function* or *class* has for input some keyword arguments, then I would need minimal list of common words associated with sed argument. Synonyms and idioms can be googled easily but i would advise against the big list of synonyms, keep it small 2-3 + attribute name . Then all we need is to *map* those aliases to the original attribute since we as codes need to know how to call attribute without calling `getattr(self,someattributestring)`

**code**:
Chronologically we must first define a function to generate aliases.

```
# generate aliases for attributes
def generateAliases(*argListNames):

    returningValues = [] # this could be omitted if user wants to make generator
    la = returningValues.append # this could be omitted also 

    #dominated argListNames
    argListNames = map( str, argListNames ) #for simplicity convert to strings
    argListNames = map( str.lower , argListNames ) #for simplicity convert to lower string
    argListNames = list(argListNames) # back to list

    # small nameless lambda functions
    getFirstChr = lambda element: element[0] # getting first character
    conectedJoing= lambda connector,item,args: connecter.join([ item, args if not __isTL__(args) else connecter.join(args) ]) # generating joined string

    # list of string convertors used to generate aliases
    convertorList= [ lambda x: x , getFirstChr , str.title , str.upper , lambda x: getFirstChr( str.upper(x) ) ]

    for item in argListNames:
        ## since we dont want alias to repeat itself
        listNoitem = filter( lambda x: x!=item , argListNames )
        listNoitem = list(listNoitem)

        la(item) # if returningValues omitted use yield statement

        for conversion in convertorList: ##1 keeping up with for loops
            converted = conversion(item)

            for connecter in "_,".split(","):

                for listItem in listNoitem:

                    for cnvrt in convertorList: ##2 cnvrt is converted second stage : used to convert the whole list of items without current alias
                        cList = cnvrt(listItem)

                        la( conectedJoing(connecter,converted,cList) )# if returningValues omitted use yield statement


                la( conectedJoing(connecter,converted,listNoitem) )# if returningValues omitted use yield statement

    # if user wanted to make generator omit next lines
    returningValues = [ x.replace("_","") if x.endswith("_") else x for x in returningValues ]
    returningValues = sorted(set(returningValues)) 
    return list( map(str,returningValues) )
```

Now we need to map and check those arguments inside **function** or **class** so we need some argument parser.

```
## **kwargs argument parser , no error
def argumentParser(AprovedSequence,**kwargs):

    # AprovedSequence is suposed to be dictionary data type with {"original argument": generateAliases(originalArgumentName,somealias,somealias,...)

    """
        phrases the keyword arguments, 
            for example :     argumentParser(AprovedSequence,someArgument=somevalue,otherArgument=othervalue ... )
        then it checks if someArgument is needed by checking in AprovedSequence if name "someArgument" is found in sequence: 
        If "someArgument" is found in AprovedSequence it stores returns dictionary of DefaultKeys : Values 
            for example: DefaultKey for someArgument: somevalue

        input: 
            argumentParser(dict: AprovedSequence, kwargs)
        returns:
            dictionary of found attributes and their values

        !!important!! kwargs are not case sensitive in this case , so go crazy as long as you get the apropriate keyword!!
        if you dont know what kind of keywords are needed for class
            just type className.errorAttributeNames()
            for example point.errorAttributeNames()

    """
    if isinstance(AprovedSequence,dict):

        di = dict.items # dictionary.values(someDict)
        dk = dict.keys  # dictionary.keys(someDict)

        # managing the kwargs and aprooved sequence data
        toLowerStr = lambda el: str(el).lower() # conversion to lower string
        asingKey = lambda el: [ key for key in dk(AprovedSequence) if toLowerStr(el) in AprovedSequence[key] ][0] # asigning key 

        return { asingKey(k):v for k,v in di(kwargs) } # dictionary comprehension
    else: 
        raise TypeError("argumentPhraser function accepts only dictionary for a AprovedSequence aka first item")
        return None
```

**implementation**

```
def somefunction(**kwargs):
    aliases = {
        "val1":generateAliases("first","1"),
        "val2":generateAliases("second","2")
    }
    aproved = argumentParser(aliases,**kwargs)

    if "val1" in aproved.keys(): val1 = aproved["val1"]
    else: val1 = 0 # seting default value for val1

    if "val2" in aproved.keys(): val2 = aproved["val2"]
    else: val2 = 1 # seting default value for val2

    #do something or your code here

    return val1,val2

# for testing purposes 
for x in [ {"first":1} , {"second":2,"first":3} , {"f1":4,"s2":5} , {"f_1":6,"2_s":7} ]:
    # displaying imputed variables 
    form = ["passed "]
    form += [ "{} as {} ".format(key,value) for key,value in x.items() ]
    # implementing somefunciton
    print( "".join(form), somefunction(**x) )
```

**output**

```
python27 -m kwtest
Process started >>>
passed first as 1  (1, 1)
passed second as 2 first as 3  (3, 2)
passed f1 as 4 s2 as 5  (4, 5)
passed 2_s as 7 f_1 as 6  (6, 7)
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)

python35 -m kwtest
Process started >>>
passed first as 1  (1, 1)
passed first as 3 second as 2  (3, 2)
passed f1 as 4 s2 as 5  (4, 5)
passed f_1 as 6 2_s as 7  (6, 7)
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
```

If implemented in classes, the process is similar in `__init__` but `__getitem__` , `__setitem__`and `__delitem__` must be coded so they could search for attribute names in aliases as well. Also attribtribute names could be generated with `self.attributes = list( aliases.keys())` or something like that.Default values could be stored in classes with `__kwdefaults__` or '**defaults**' depending what kind of data your function is using.

this code has been tested on py2.7 and py3.5 as you can see.

**further explanation if needed**
You can define aliases within class global attributes or within `__init__`.
Explaining further `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self,item):
    if item in self.aliases.keys():
         return getattr(self,item)
    if any( item in value for value in self.aliases.values() ):
         item = [ key for key in self.aliases.keys() if item in self.aliases[key] ] [0]
         return getattr(self,item)
    if item in range( len( self.aliases.keys() ) ): 
         item = list( self.aliases.keys() )[item]
         return getattr(self,item)
```

Explaining further `__setitem__`:

```
def __setitem__(self,item,value):
    item = self.__getitem__(self,item)
    #? must have `__dict__` method or class needs to be instanced from object like class someclass(object) 
    item = [ key for key in vars(self).items() if self[key] == item] [0]
    if item != None:
        setattr(self,item,value)
```