# Change a function argument name in Python

Tags: python, function

I have a function which take countries argument

```
getStats(countries=['France','Spain','Italy','US'])
```

I want to reuse exactly the same function but I would like to change the name argument countries to regions

```
getStats(regions=['New York','Boston','San Francisco'])
```

What is the good way to proceed ? Is it a decorator case ?

Comment: [Check answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784308/keyword-arguments-aliases-in-python).

Comment: What about simply renaming the parameter? Maybe something broader like `locations`? Or can you not edit the function?

Comment: And don't use lists as default arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Is `countries`/`regions` the only argument to the function?

Comment: @khelwood, in fact there are more than one argument getStats(countries=['France','Spain','Italy','US'], type=type which=['l1','l2','l3'], output='pandas')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would the function know which list to use in the default case `getStats()`? Assuming your function works exactly the same with countries and regions and you want to supply defaults for both, then make them lists outside the function that a user can apply. As mentioned, the parameter name can be more vague `getStats(location)` and require a list, but the user has handy default ones available.

```
countries = ['France','Spain','Italy','US']
regions = ['New York','Boston','San Francisco'])

def getStats(location):
    """Get stats for location. Default `countries` and `regions` lists
    available."""
    ....
```

Or, if you prefer, define multiple functions that call the common one.

```
def getStatsByCountry(countries=['France','Spain','Italy','US']):
    return getStats(countries)

def getStatsByRegion(regions=['New York','Boston','San Francisco']):
    return getStats(regions)
```

Comment: use location instead of countries and regions is a good idea.